# retrofit gson converter for nested json with different objects

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I've JSON structure like follows -

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Registration Complete.",
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "username": "user88",
            "email": "user@domain.com",
            "created_on": "1426171225",
            "last_login": null,
            "active": "1",
            "first_name": "User",
            "last_name": "",
            "company": null,
            "phone": null,
            "sign_up_mode": "GOOGLE_PLUS"
        }
    }
}
```

Above format is common . Only `data` key can hold different types of information like `user`, `product`, `invoice` etc.

I want to keep `status`, `message` and `data` keys same in every rest response. `data` will be treated according to `status` and `message` will be displayed to user.

So basically, above format is desired in all apis. **Only information inside `data` key will be different each time.**

And I've setup a following class and set it up as gson converter - **MyResponse.java**

```
public class MyResponse<T> implements Serializable{
    private boolean status ;
    private String message ;
    private T data;

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**Deserializer.java**

```
class Deserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T>{
    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException{
        JsonElement content = je.getAsJsonObject();

        // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion to this deserializer
        return new Gson().fromJson(content, type);

    }
}
```

And used it as follows -

```
GsonBuilder  gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES); 
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(MyResponse.class, new Deserializer<MyResponse>());
...... ..... ....

restBuilder.setConverter(new GsonConverter(gsonBuilder.create()));
```

**Service interface** is as follows -

```
@POST("/register")
public void test1(@Body MeUser meUser, Callback<MyResponse<MeUser>> apiResponseCallback);


@POST("/other")
public void test2(Callback<MyResponse<Product>> apiResponseCallback);
```

***Problem***

I can access `status` and `message` fields from inside callback. But information inside `data` key is not parsed and model like `MeUser` and `Product` always returns as empty.

If I change json structure to following above code works perfectly -

```
{
        "status": true,
        "message": "Registration Complete.",
        "data": {                
                "username": "user88",
                "email": "user@domain.com",
                "created_on": "1426171225",
                "last_login": null,
                "active": "1",
                "first_name": "User",
                "last_name": "",
                "company": null,
                "phone": null,
                "sign_up_mode": "GOOGLE_PLUS"
        }
    }
```

How can I have it worked with specifying separate key inside `data` object and parse it successfully ?

Comment: would like to know what you are doing

Comment: GSON dont take into account the generic data types `private T data;` while parsing. It has to be some specific data type.

Comment: use this data class instead of `T`. `class DataClass {
  @SerializedName("user")
  UserClass user;// user object

  @SerializedName("product")
  ProductClass product;// product object

  @SerializedName("invoice")
  InvoiceClass invoice;// invoice object

  class UserClass {

  }

  class ProductClass {

  }

  class InvoiceClass {

  }
 }`

Comment: So you are always going to know ahead of time whether you expect the JSON to parse to a `MyResponse<User>` or a `MyResponse<Product>`, etc? Or should Gson figure that out by itself - only by looking at the JSON and without the guidance you give by declaring the concrete type in the Retrofit interface? Your Retrofit example interface leads me to think that the former is true - in that case you could write (and register!) a `JsonDeserializer<MyResponse<YourClass>>` for each of your classes.

Comment: @Gimali  If I good understood you. You want to add new field inside of data f.e. user. Is that right?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak   Yea. Exactly. This can be some other for other api like product or something.

Comment: To good understanding - because I think that I know  how to do this - the data will be looks like : "data": {  "type"  : "user" ...} and will you know all of types or can you define this "type"  : "user" outside of "data"?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak Yea I know such keys in advance. See structure of json at start of question. Or maybe if there's better approach of doing this kinda of thing with some different json its also welcomed. You could suggest some if that gonna make things easier. :)

Comment: I did, it works for me If you have some question or you need some different json just ask, I have more solution for this :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I can suggest to change something in json is that you have to add at one new field that defines the type of data, so json should look like below:

```
{
   "status": true,
   "message": "Registration Complete.",
   "dataType" : "user",
   "data": {                
            "username": "user88",
            "email": "user@domain.com",
            "created_on": "1426171225",
            "last_login": null,
            "active": "1",
            "first_name": "User",
            "last_name": "",
            "company": null,
            "phone": null,
            "sign_up_mode": "GOOGLE_PLUS"
    }
}
```

The `MyResponse` class has to have new filed `DataType` so it should look like below:

```
public class MyResponse<T> implements Serializable{
    private boolean status ;
    private String message ;
    private DataType dataType ;
    private T data;


    public DataType getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }

    //... other getters and setters
}
```

The `DataType` is an enum which defines type of data. You have to pass Data.class as param in constructor. For all data types you have to create new classes. `DataType` enum should look like below:

```
public enum DataType {

    @SerializedName("user")
    USER(MeUser.class),
    @SerializedName("product")
    Product(Product.class),
    //other types in the same way, the important think is that 
    //the SerializedName value should be the same as dataType value from json 
    ;


    Type type;

    DataType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Type getType(){
        return type;
    }
}
```

The desarializator for Json should looks like below:

```
public class DeserializerJson implements JsonDeserializer<MyResponse> {

    @Override
    public MyResponse deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
            throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject content = je.getAsJsonObject();
        MyResponse message = new Gson().fromJson(je, type);
        JsonElement data = content.get("data");
        message.setData(new Gson().fromJson(data, message.getDataType().getType()));
        return message;

    }
}
```

And when you create `RestAdapter`, in the line where you register Deserializator, you should use this :

```
 .registerTypeAdapter(MyResponse.class, new DeserializerJson())
```

Other classes (types of data) you define like standard POJO for Gson in separated classes.

Comment: Is it possible to return whole json response as an object of MyResponse.class with `success` and `message ` field as well? Im gonba need it to display message according to status and message field. Right now it returns only data key. Just have to tweak the `DeserializerJson` right??

Comment: Oops. It does what I need already. Great. I'll check if this fits with other jsons also. Looks clean and neat now. :)

Comment: What mean "Right now it returns only data key. Just have to tweak the DeserializerJson right?" It should create full MyResponse object with right data.

Comment: Yea. I didn't read code completely before commenting. I'm checking this right now.

Comment: OK. Cool. With this technique if in place  of  `user` I can use like for example `productList` and have a list of products ?? I'll sure define this new type in enum also. Right?? Means `dataType` would be `productList` and `data` can now hold array of objecta of type Product.class ??

Comment: basically yes but I didn't test it for array.Something like this will be working  {
   "status": true,
   "message": "Registration Complete.",
   "dataType" : "productList",
   "data": {                
            productList[{
              //json for pfroduct
            },
            {
              //json for pfroduct
            }]]
    }
}

Comment: @Gimali If you need some explanation We can talk on chat

Comment: What happens if the inner object contains a Date field? 

 .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(GenericNotificationResponse.class, new NotificationDeserializer())
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .create();

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because the `data` attribute is defined as `T` which you expect to be of types `MeUser`, `Product`, etc, but is actually of an object which has inner attribute like `user`. To resolve this, you need to introduce another level of classes which has the required attributes `user`, `product`, `invoice` etc. This can be easily achieved using static inner classes.

```
public class MeUser{
  private User user;
  public static class User{
    private String username;
    //add other attributes of the User class
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any by which I can tell converter to treat first object inside data as  type and not data itself?

Comment: None that I know of. Perhaps @JakeWharton can explain.

Answer (score -1):

Might be a little bit off-topic, but what happens if the inner object contains a Date property? My TypeAdapter looks like this:

```
 .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(GenericNotificationResponse.class, new NotificationDeserializer())
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .create();
```

But due to the parsing which is done by this :  `message.setData(new Gson().fromJson(data, message.getDataType().getType()));`

It will throw an error whenever it will try to deserialize the Date property. Is there a quick fix for this?

EDIT: Marked the answer as accepted, definitely :) it helped me fix my issue. But now there's this problem with the date deserializer.